# App from mac to iphone

Tags: python, ios, macos

I have built an app with `py2app.` It is a simple GUI.

How to transfer the app to iOS?

Comment: *"If Python runs on an iPhone"* - it doesn't. Also, iOS apps aren't the same as Mac apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to run this app on an iPhone.  First, there's no python interpreter.  Your best bet is to port the app to an Xcode project, and do it natively.

Alternatively, you could try and use [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home).